# Power Apps Gallery Filter based on two values

Tags: powerapps-formula

I am busy creating my first power app and have hit a snag when trying to filter a gallery (SharePoint Linked) based on multiple values. I have three formulas for now as follows:

```
Filter([@'Demo Stock']; StartsWith('Part Number'; txt_ItemSearch.Text)
Filter('Demo Stock';Warehouse.Value=WarehouseFilter.SelectedText.Value)
Filter('Demo Stock';'Item Status'.Value="Available")
```

Each of these work independently. What would the syntax be to use all of these filters together?

This does not work:

```
SortByColumns(Filter([@'Demo Stock']; StartsWith('Part Number'; txt_ItemSearch.Text);'Demo Stock';Warehouse.Value=WarehouseFilter.SelectedText.Value;'Demo Stock';'Item Status'.Value="Available");"Part Number";Ascending)
```

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the solution. Not sure if its the most elegant but it works.

```
Filter([@'Demo Stock']; StartsWith('Part Number'; txt_ItemSearch.Text);(Warehouse.Value=WarehouseFilter.SelectedText.Value);('Item Status'.Value="Available"))
```